# NightwatchJS and Docker

Tags: selenium, docker, nightwatch.js

I am currently trying to setup NightwatchJS within our current Docker setup. Therefor I am using this boilerplate as a start point: https://github.com/ChrisZie/nightwatch-boilerplate

I have taken the snippets from the docker-compose.json and added them to mine. In general it is working very good and the tests are running. The issue I am facing is that Nightwatch is not able to reach the sites which are provided by my Nginx container. Sites which are provided via the internet are working fine. I also tried to ping the sites from the Nginx container while i was connected to the Selenium container which worked out without any issue, which actually confused me even more.

Any clue what might go wrong here?

Comment: can you try curl instead of ping? i think they access different protocols/ports. i suspect there is a corporate firewall blocking the request

Comment: Alright I will give this a shot. But am I on the right track the the selenium container must be able to connect to the nginx?

Answer (score 0):

Does your docker-compose create all three containers (hub / node / nginx server)? If so, try using the depends_on flag on the nginx container:

```
  depends_on:
  - selenium-node-chrome
  - selenium-hub
```

Example:
https://gist.github.com/jackTheRipper/db13c68c2ec78e50d03ac55f06da9726

Also, what URL are you trying to access the nginx server at? "localhost" probably won't work, if the name of the container description in docker-compose is "nginx", try accessing it at "nginx:80"